# Compare SQL Server Performance of In-Memory vs Disk Tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, in-memory-tables, in-memory-oltp

I want to detect the performance improvements after migrating a table to be In-memory table.

Are there any methods/tools that help me to do that?

Comment: Benchmarking a design is the same no matter what storage is used. You need to execute a test payload and gather metrics like IO,latency etc.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at [Brent Ozar's articles on load testing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/category/development/load-testing/) like [How to Check Performance on a New SQL Server](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/08/how-to-check-performance-on-a-new-sql-server/) and [How to Fake Load Tests with SQLQueryStress](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/05/how-to-fake-load-tests-with-sqlquerystress/)

Comment: Do you mean a memory optimised table like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-2017 Generally speaking, memory optimised tables are only faster if they are accompanied (accessed by) a natively compiled stored procedure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/native-compilation-of-tables-and-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-2017